# How to order known values as columns in Dynamic Pivot and new ones to the end?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am setting up a dynamic pivot where the columns (Department IDs) must be in a set order and any new values that will create a column must be at the end of the table.  I set up a Sequence number for the "known" departments and any new departments get the next number in the sequence.  I need the Department IDs to be the headings but I need them in the order of the Sequence number.

1) I have pivoted on the Sequence number:

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [SEQ] FROM #TABLE) AS [SEQ]
ORDER BY  [SEQ]

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [DATE], ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #TABLE
    PIVOT(SUM([COUNT]) 
          FOR [SEQ] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable
          ORDER BY [DATE]'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This comes out in the correct order but the Sequence number is the column heading

2) I also have pivoted on the Dept but the columns are in the sequence of the Dept ID:

```
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([DEPT_ID])

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DEPT_ID] FROM #TABLE) AS [DEPT_ID]
ORDER BY  [DEPT_ID]

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [DATE], ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #TABLE
    PIVOT(SUM([COUNT]) 
          FOR [DEPT_ID] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable
          ORDER BY [DATE]'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

The data/table that is ready to be pivoted is:

```
SEQ    DEPT     DATE     COUNT
----------------------------------
1       8       1/1/2019  5      (Dept 8 is known Dept)
1       8       1/2/2019  7
2       3       1/1/2019  6      (Dept 3 is known Dept)
2       3       1/2/2019  4
3       1       1/1/2019  7      (Dept 1 is an unknown dept)
3       1       1/2/2019  3
```

The results I want to see are:

```
DATE        8     3     1
----------------------------------
1/1/2019    5     6     7
1/2/2019    7     4     3
```

[Or as an image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oro5.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using a dynamic query and `PIVOT`:

```
-- declare the variables.
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- set the columns (ORDER BY SEQ).
SET @ColumnName = STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DEPT))
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY SEQ, DEPT
    ORDER BY SEQ
    FOR XML PATH('')
) , 1 , 1 , '')

-- set the pivot query to get the result.
SET @DynamicQuery = N'
    SELECT [DATE], ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (
        SELECT DEPT, DATE, COUNT
        FROM table_name
    ) st PIVOT(
        SUM([COUNT]) 
        FOR [DEPT] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
    ) pt
    ORDER BY [DATE]'

-- execute the dynamic query.
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a600cb6426f3632130c4c88d4eda4d16)

---

In case the order of the columns doesn't matter you can use the following solution:

```
-- pivot query without specific order of columns.
SELECT DATE, [8], [3], [1]  
FROM (
    SELECT DEPT, DATE, COUNT
    FROM table_name
) st PIVOT (  
    SUM(COUNT)
    FOR DEPT IN ([8], [3], [1])   
) pt
ORDER BY [DATE];
```